Receive Broadcast Intent in BroadcastReceiver when an application is started (which intent to listen to?)
I am trying to receive a Broadcast Intent to check which app is being launched currently.
(In order to send a Notification/Popup, reminding the user)
in my Manifest file:
<receiver
      android:name=".domain.background.receiver.OpenedApplicationBroadcastReceiver"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>

And do something in the receiver:
class OpenedApplicationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    // do something if it is application xyz
    }
}

But so far this isn't working.
But I am also quite clueless what to put in my <intent-filter> in order to receive such broadcast.
What do I need to change so that my code works?


I am trying to receive a Broadcast Intent to check which app is being launched currently

There is no such broadcast.

what could I use instead to get similar functionality?
I was thinking about a Service that checks what app is running via ActivityManager.
Although that doesn't seem that elegant and resource-saving.

@Owlon: "I was thinking about a Service that checks what app is running via ActivityManager" -- that is not possible on any recent version of Android, for security and privacy reasons.

so there is no possible option to get similar functionality? Because there are f.e. AppBlockers that add a pin to an app that you have to enter on startup.

@Owlon: I do not know what they do. I know that the two techniques that you described will not work.

you can register a broadcast receiver for the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED and ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED intents. These intents are broadcasted when a new package is installed or replaced, which will tell that an app is being launched.
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String action = intent.getAction();
if (action != null && (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) ||action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED))) {
    String packageName = intent.getDataString();
    Log.d("PackageChangeReceiver", "Package added/replaced: " + packageName);

    // You can check the package name to find which app is being launched
}

}
this should be done in Manifest file.
<receiver android: name=".dBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android: name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android: name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android: scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


Package added and package replaced are broadcast when an app is installed or updated. These are NOT broadcast when an app is launched/started.
